# Overlay transparent circle on camera preview in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, camera, face-recognition, android-camera-intent

Recently Uber has released a Face Recognition feature and I'm trying to create a similar camera preview it looks like this :

[image]

I need to create a transparent circle to focus the users face to the camera. I have tried to create it from some other posted and tried to look into a similar use cases like in Zxing barcode scanner, but I still can't achieve the expected result

Comment: Were you able to achieve this? Is yes, could you please post some answer.

Comment: got any solution?